# how to make a well conform width wise?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, width

I haven't used bootstrap much, but I'm trying to create a registration form for a web application.

The well seems to conform around the captcha and captcha input just fine when it comes to height, but when it comes to width, it maximizes its full length. Is there a way to make the well conform width wise as it does height wise?

[image: Screenshot of the form]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: http://pastebin.com/uVvuxWP7 <-- The page code, for CSS, I'm just using the bootstrap.css file ---> http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css

Comment: Could you post the HTML / CSS you wrote to get the result above? There's not much for us to recommend otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input confirms to the center, and so does the captcha. The input is further constraint by the class=span2 you have in your input.

```
  <input class="span2" name="username" id="prependedInput" type="text" required/>
```

There's no span2 on your well.

```
<div class="well well-small">
```

Have a look at some form examples on bootsnip like [this](http://bootsnipp.com/snipps/credit-card-payment-form-2) one.